# Maximo Integration With External JSON API

Tags: json, rest, jython, maximo

I have found various methods of invoking a JSON/REST API call from Maximo to an external system on the web, but none of them have matched exactly what I'm looking for and all of them seem to use different methods, which is causing me a lot of confusion because I am EXTREMELY rusty at jython coding. So, hopefully, you all can help me out. Please be as detailed as possible: script language, script type (for integration, object launch point, publish channel process/user exit class, etc).
My Maximo Environment is 7.6.1.1. I have created the following...

Maximo Object Structure (MXSRLEAK): with 3 objects (SR, TKSERVICEADDRESS, and WORKLOG)

Maximo Publish Channel (MXSRLEAK-PC): uses the MXSRLEAK OS and contains my processing rules to skip records if they don't meet the criteria (SITEID = 'TWOO', TEMPLATEID IN ('LEAK','LEAKH','LEAKW'), HISTORYFLAG = 0)

Maximo End Point (LEAKTIX): HTTP Handler, HEADERS ("Content-Type:application/json"), HTTPMETHOD ("POST"), URL (https:///api/ticket/?ticketid=), USERNAME ("Maximo"), and PASSWORD (). The Allow Override is checked for HEADERS, HTTPMETHOD, and URL.

At this point, I need an automation script to:

1. Limit the Maximo attributes that I'm sending. This will vary depending on what happens on the Maximo side. If an externally created (SOURCE = LEAKREP, EXTERNALRECID IS NOT NULL) service request ticket gets cancelled, I need to send the last worklog with logtype = "CANCOMM" (Both summary/description and details/description_longdescription) as well as the USERID that changed status. If an externally created SR ticket gets closed, I need to send the last worklog with logtype <> "CANCOMM". If the externally created SR ticket was a duplicate, I need to also include a custom field called "DUPLICATE" (which uses a table domain to show all open SR's with similar TEMPLATEID's in the UI). If a "LEAK" SR ticket originated in Maximo (doesn't have a SOURCE or EXTERNALRECID), then I need to send data from the SR (ex. DESCRIPTION, REPORTDATE, REPORTEDBY, etc), TKSERVICEADDRESS (FORMATTEDADDRESS,etc), and WORKLOG (DESCRIPTION, LONGDESCRIPTION if they exist) objects to the external system and parse the response to update SOURCE and EXTERNALRECID.
2. Update Maximo End Point values for API call: HTTPMETHOD to "POST" or "PATCH", Add HEADERS (Authorization: Basic Base64Userid/Password), etc.

Below is my latest attempt with an automation script, which doesn't work because the "mbo is not defined" (I'm sure there are more problems with it but it fails early on in script). The script was created for integration, with a publish channel (MXSRLEAK-PC) using the External Exit option in Jython. I was trying to start with just one scenario where the Maximo SR ticket was originally created via an API call from the external system into Maximo and was actually a duplicate of another Maximo SR ticket. My thought was if I got this part correct, I could update the script to include the other scenarios, such as if the SR ticket originated in Maximo and needed to POST a new record to external system.

My final question is, is it better (easier for future eyes to understand) to have one Object Structure, Publish Channel, End Point, and Automation Script to handle all scenarios or to create separate ones for each scenario?

```
from com.ibm.json.java import JSONObject
from java.io import BufferedReader, IOException, InputStreamReader
from java.lang import System, Class, String, StringBuffer
from java.nio.charset import Charset
from java.util import Date, Properties, List, ArrayList, HashMap
from org.apache.commons.codec.binary import Base64
from org.apache.http import HttpEntity, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpVersion
from org.apache.http.client import ClientProtocolException, HttpClient
from org.apache.http.client.entity import UrlEncodedFormEntity
from org.apache.http.client.methods import HttpPost
from org.apache.http.entity import StringEntity
from org.apache.http.impl.client import DefaultHttpClient
from org.apache.http.message import BasicNameValuePair
from org.apache.http.params import BasicHttpParams, HttpParams, HttpProtocolParamBean
from psdi.mbo import Mbo, MboRemote, MboSet, MboSetRemote
from psdi.security import UserInfo
from psdi.server import MXServer
from psdi.iface.router import Router
from sys import *

leakid = mbo.getString("EXTERNALRECID")
#Attempting to pull current SR worklog using object relationship and attribute
maxlog = mbo.getString("DUPWORKLOG.description")
maxloglong = mbo.getString("DUPWORKLOG.description_longdescription")

clientEndpoint = Router.getHandler("LEAKTIX")
cEmap = HashMap()
host = cEmap.get("URL")+leakid
method = cEmap.get("HTTPMETHOD")
currhead = cEmap.get("HEADERS")
tixuser = cEmap.get("USERNAME")
tixpass = cEmap.get("PASSWORD")
auth = tixuser + ":" + tixpass
authHeader = String(Base64.encodeBase64(String.getBytes(auth, 'ISO-8859-1')),"UTF-8")

def createJSONstring():
    jsonStr = ""
    obj = JSONObject()
    obj.put("status_code", "1")
    obj.put("solution", "DUPLICATE TICKET")
    obj.put("solution_notes", maxlog+" "+maxloglong)
    jsonStr = obj.serialize(True)
    return jsonStr
def httpPost(path, jsonstring):
    params = BasicHttpParams()
    paramsBean = HttpProtocolParamBean(params)
    paramsBean.setVersion(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1)
    paramsBean.setContentCharset("UTF-8")
    paramsBean.setUseExpectContinue(True)
    entity = StringEntity(jsonstring, "UTF-8")
    client = DefaultHttpClient()
    request = HttpPost(host)
    request.setParams(params)
    #request.addHeader(currhead)
    request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
    request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic "+authHeader)
    request.setEntity(entity)
    response = client.execute(request)
    status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
    obj = JSONObject.parse(response.getEntity().getContent())
    System.out.println(str(status)+": "+str(obj))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Rick! I don't have time to give a full answer, but I suggest you spend some time with the Help documentation on using Automation Scripts for integration (accessible from the Help menu in the Automation Scripts application), and with the [Maximo API JavaDocs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/javadocs-maximo-asset-management-76) for the StructureData class.

Comment: Preacher, if you are referring to the irData method, I've tried that. I hate having to ask for assistance on this, but I've tried every way I could think of, which is why I reached out for help here. I do truly appreciate you responding though... at least someone has seen my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. Ideally, the external exit script doesn’t have mbo as its instance. Instead, it uses irdata after breaking the structure data. Then another manipulation comes.

What I understood is that you need to post the payload dynamically based on some conditions in Maximo. For that, I think you can write a custom handler which will be called during the post.